# awk issue selecting lines between two patterns

Tags: linux, awk, scripting, email

"Issue"... The command is doing what is actually instructed to.

Given this mbox format file:

```
From: me@my.dom #identifies the beginning of the first mail    
...
Subject: crcheck.sh #identifies the beginning of the mail body
...
MYVARIABLE="123"
...
From: me@my.dom #identifies the beginning of the next mail
...
Subject: crcheck.sh #identifies the beginning of the mail body
...
From: another@evil.dom #identifies the beginning of next mail
...
Subject: crcheck.sh #identifies the beginning of the mail body
EVILVARIABLE="0.00" #just to mention a value that would cause division by zero errors and crash my main script.
...
From: me@my.dom #identifies the beginning of the next mail
...
```

I need to select all lines between a valid Subject: and the next From:, but the From: preceiding the Subject line should be the $GOODSENDER one.

The code I'm running:

```
GOODSUBJECT="crcheck.sh"
GOODSENDER="me@my.dom"
cat $MBOX |awk "/Subject\: $GOODSUBJECT$/{a=1}/From\:\ $GOODSENDER /{print;a=0}a"|grep $i\=\"
```

Outputs:

```
MYVARIABLE="123"
EVILVARIABLE="0.00"
```

Expected output:

```
MYVARIABLE="123"
```

The command is doing what it's instructed to, as those lines are acutally between two of the lines I set as patterns for awk.

But how can I adjust it to have this desidered behaviour?

Comment: I don't see `"crcheck.sh"` subject in your input. Will you update the input?

Comment: TY for your attention, it's everywhere. I edited the question.

Comment: some kind of duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46245806/bash-script-to-change-other-scripts-variables-awk-issue-selecting-lines-betwee#46245806

Comment: TY sir, the other post on SO turned into a best practice coding contest, and it was probably my fault, because the question was all about this single awk line. I'm going to delete the SO one, as soon as the guy telling me that the error was all about my bad coding practices will reply. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk "/Subject:/{a=0} /From:/{a=0; b=0} a && b && /MYVARIABLE=/{print} /Subject: crcheck.sh$/{a=1} /From: me@my.dom/{b=1}" mbox
MYVARIABLE="123"
```

#### How it works

- `/Subject:/{a=0} /From:/{a=0; b=0}`

  When we reach a subject or from line, turn all flags false.
- `a && b && /MYVARIABLE=/{print}`

  If both flags are true and the line includes the string `MYVARIABLE=`, then print the line.
- `/Subject: crcheck.sh$/{a=1}`

  If the subject line is good, set flag `a` to true.
- `/From: me@my.dom/{b=1}`

  If the from line is good, set flag `b` to true.

#### Notes

1. It is poor practice to use all caps for shell variables.  The system use all caps for its variables and you don't want to accidentally overwrite one of them.
2. `cat` is unneeded.  Awk takes file names as arguments.
3. In regexes, `:` and space are not special.  They don't need to be escaped.
4. In email headers, `Subject:` and `From:` are both supposed to start at the beginning of the line.  A better regex for each might be `/^Subject:/` and `/^From:/` where `^` is the regex symbol for start-of-line.

#### Passing a variable to awk

```
$ var=MYVARIABLE
$ awk -v x="$var" '/Subject:/{a=0} /From:/{a=0; b=0} a && b && $0 ~ (x"="){print} /Subject: crcheck.sh$/{a=1} /From: me@my.dom/{b=1}' mbox
MYVARIABLE="123"
```

#### Sample Input

The output above was generated using this as the input file:

```
$ cat mbox
From: me@my.dom
...
Subject: crcheck.sh
...
MYVARIABLE="123"
...
From: me@my.dom
...
Subject: crcheck.sh
...
From: another@evil.dom
...
Subject: crcheck.sh
EVILVARIABLE="0.00"
...
From: me@my.dom
...
```

This is the same as in the question except that, to restore it to mbox format, the added comments have been removed.

Comment: this won't print anything on the OP's input: https://ibb.co/fXxSPQ

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest The OP's "input" has comments.  From the question, it was clear that the comments weren't in the input he was testing with.  So, I removed the comments.  With comments removed, the code produces for me exactly the output that I show.  I will update the answer showing the input I use.

Comment: there's no output for me too! `user@host:~$ cat /var/mail/user |awk "/Subject:/{a=0} /From:/{a=0; b=0} a && b{print} /Subject\: $/{a=1} /From: me@my.dom/{b=1}"` `user@host:~$ `

Comment: @Marco OK.  There are two reasons for that.  (1) The code that you are testing is different from my code.  Your code includes the command `/Subject\: $/{a=1}` which will only trigger if the subject line consists of a single space.  This likely never happened in your file.  (2) I can't debug the output from your `/var/mail/user` file since I don't know what is in it.  While we are debugging, please use the sample input from the question (but with the comments removed as shown in my answer).  Thanks.

Comment: You're right, your code works with sample INPUT. But I think I'm messing it up when putting it into the script. This is the original unmasked line: `for g in $(cat $MBOX |awk "/Subject\: $GOODSUBJECT$/{a=1}/From\:\ $GOODSENDER /{print;a=0}a"|grep $i\=\"); do`. I know I should use a `while read`here.

Comment: @Marco Very good.  What is `$i`?

Comment: We are in a for (each existing variable of the main script that can be modified by this one). This grep ensures that no lines but the variables one can be taken into account by this script and can be modified in the production script.

Comment: @Marco I have updated the answer to do what I think you want from the grep command.  Have a look at it and let me know.

Comment: Are you still sure about your last edit after my $i explanation?

Comment: The update is `a && b && /MYVARIABLE=/{print}`.  This means that only lines in the right range (both a and b true) __and__ matching `MYVARIABLE=` will print.  If you wanted something else, please explain.

Comment: Ok, but MYVAR is "dynamic" in the for, it's a $i. If this way it's fine, then your update is.

Comment: @Marco OK.  I just added to the answer a section to show how to pass a variable MYVAR to the awk script.

Comment: TY very much for your extra hints, too!