# awk delete matching lines after mbox parse

Tags: shell-script, awk, scripting, email

Following suggestions from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392518/awk-issue-selecting-lines-between-two-patterns) I'm using the following line in a script to read a mbox file format and do some operations non relevant to the question.

```
awk "/^Subject\: $GOODSUBJECT$/{a=1}/^From\:\ $GOODSENDER /{print;a=0}a" $MBOX
```

How would I delete all the lines selected by this match after my script has done its job?

Please note that they might not be deleted one by one by matching them, like I could do with `sed`, because - for instance - if I'll match a whitespace all lines with withespaces would be deleted in all mails.

I want to delete just the lines delimited by this `awk` selection instead.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Just do reverse match to keep those that doesn't match with:

```
awk "!/^Subject\: $GOODSUBJECT$/{a=1} !/^From\:\ $GOODSENDER /{print;a=0}a" $MBOX
```